# docker SHM_SIZE /dev/shm: resizing shared memory

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I want to resize `postgres` container's shared memory from default `64M`. So I add:

```
build:
      context: .
      shm_size: '2gb'
```

I'm using version 3.6 of the compose file, `postgres` service definition.

```
version: "3.6"

services:

 #other services go here..
 postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:10
    hostname: postgres
    container_name: fiware-postgres
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    build:
      context: .
      shm_size: '2gb'
```

However, this change doesn't take effect even though I restart the service `docker-compose down` then `up`. So Immediately I start interacting with postgres to display some data on dashboard, I get shared memory issue.

Before lunching the dashboard:

```
$docker exec -it fiware-postgres df -h
Filesystem                                                                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-253:1-107615-1541c55e4c3d5e03a7716d5418eea4c520b6556a6fd179c6ab769afd0ce64d9f   10G  266M  9.8G   3% /
tmpfs                                                                                              64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                                                                                         197G   52G  136G  28% /etc/hosts
shm                                                                                                64M  8.0K   64M   1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/firmware
```

After lunching the dashboard:

```
$docker exec -it fiware-postgres df -h
Filesystem                                                                                        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/docker-253:1-107615-1541c55e4c3d5e03a7716d5418eea4c520b6556a6fd179c6ab769afd0ce64d9f   10G  266M  9.8G   3% /
tmpfs                                                                                              64M     0   64M   0% /dev
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/vda1                                                                                         197G   52G  136G  28% /etc/hosts
shm                                                                                                64M   50M   15M  78% /dev/shm
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /proc/acpi
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /proc/scsi
tmpfs                                                                                             1.4G     0  1.4G   0% /sys/firmware
```

postgres error log:

```
2019-07-01 17:27:58.802 UTC [47] ERROR:  could not resize shared memory segment "/PostgreSQL.1145887853" to 12615680 bytes: No space left on device
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You set `shm_size` in `build`, this will just affect build, you need to set it in service level, like next:

**docker-compose.yaml:**

```
version: "3.6"

services:

 #other services go here..
 postgres:
    restart: always
    image: postgres:10
    hostname: postgres
    container_name: fiware-postgres
    expose:
      - "5432"
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    networks:
      - default
    environment:
      - "POSTGRES_PASSWORD=password"
      - "POSTGRES_USER=postgres"
      - "POSTGRES_DB=postgres"
    volumes:
      - ./postgres-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
    build:
      context: .
      shm_size: 256mb
    shm_size: 512mb
```

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM postgres:10

RUN df -h | grep shm
```

Then, `docker-compose up -d --build` to start it and check:

```
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/66$ docker-compose --version
docker-compose version 1.24.0, build 0aa59064
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/66$ docker-compose up -d --build
Building postgres
Step 1/2 : FROM postgres:10
 ---> 0959974989f8
Step 2/2 : RUN df -h | grep shm
 ---> Running in 25d341cfde9c
shm             256M     0  256M   0% /dev/shm
Removing intermediate container 25d341cfde9c
 ---> 1637f1afcb81

Successfully built 1637f1afcb81
Successfully tagged postgres:10
Recreating fiware-postgres ... done
shubuntu1@shubuntu1:~/66$ docker exec -it fiware-postgres df -h | grep shm
shm             512M  8.0K  512M   1% /dev/shm
```

You can see in build time it shows `256m`, but the runtime container it shows `512m`.

Answer (score 11):

This happened because Postgres wrote over 64MB to the shared memory (`/dev/shm` under Linux). In default Linux settings, the max shared memory size is 64M.

**Verification**

1. We can use the following command to verify this:

```
0d807385d325:/usr/src# df -h | grep shm
shm             64.0M     0  64.0M   0% /dev/shm
```

2. And we can manually adjust the max shared memory by configuring docker-compose.yml like (adjusting it to 4MB, https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#shm_size):

```
services:
  my_service:
    ....
    tty: true
    shm_size: '4mb'
```

3. After changing it to 4MB, verify it again:

```
0d807385d325:/usr/src# df -h | grep shm
shm             4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev/shm
```

4. We cannot write over 4MB data into shared memory device after this:

```
# write 4MB (1kb * 4096) to /dev/shm/test file succeeds
0d807385d325:/usr/src# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/test bs=1024 count=4096 
4096+0 records in
4096+0 records out
4194304 bytes (4.2 MB, 4.0 MiB) copied, 0.0042619 s, 984 MB/s


# write 4.001MB (1kb * 4097) to /dev/shm/test file fails
0d807385d325:/usr/src# dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/shm/test bs=1024 count=4097 
dd: error writing '/dev/shm/test': No space left on device
4097+0 records in
4096+0 records out
4194304 bytes (4.2 MB, 4.0 MiB) copied, 0.0041456 s, 1.0 GB/s
```

**Fix for this issue**

We simply adjust this value to be a bigger value.

1. For `docker run`, we can use the `--shm-size` to adjust it (https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/)
2. For docker-compose, we can use the `shm_size` option in docker-compose file to adjust it like above (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#shm_size)
3. For Kubernetes, we have to use the `emptyDir` option in Kubernetes (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir). Basically, we need to:

3.1) add a new `emptyDir` volume with "Memory" as medium

```
volumes:                          
    - name: dshm
      emptyDir:
        medium: Memory
```

3.2) Mount it to the `/dev/shm` for the stonewave container

```
volumeMounts:                 
        - mountPath: /dev/shm
          name: dshm
```

According to Kubernetes's documentation (https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir), it will use 50% of the memory as the max by default.

> If the SizeMemoryBackedVolumes feature gate is enabled, you can specify a size for memory backed volumes. If no size is specified, memory backed volumes are sized to 50% of the memory on a Linux host.

**References**

- https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/shared_memory.html
- https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#emptydir
- https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#shm_size